# How do I make a short anonymous URL link for a website?

Tags: anonymity, web-proxy, url, website

I want to create a short website link that anonymizes both the people going to the content of the site and partly the source of that sites content.
I once saw a site that could shrink the URL and anonymise it by loading the site through a Tor proxy.

Comment: your question does not make sense, isn't related to tor and definitely not to obfsproxy - as far as i can tell what you are looking for is http referer anonymization - if so, it has nothing to do with network anonymity like it is provided by tor

Comment: To achieve anonymity the communicating parties should either **1.** directly use some kind of anonymization network which does not rely on trusted components (for example the Tor network) or you must **2.** trust the anonymization components (like proxies). ------ To use **1.** you must have a software to communicate in the anonymization network installed so a sole link does not solve your problem.